# Maybe I'm wrong, What am I?

Tags: riddle, word, rhyme

Chances are you've heard of me,
Some call me an oracle.
Am I friend, or enemy?
I'm rather affordable.

College, University,
I'm the savior late at night.
Beware, not all that you see,
Is truth or fully right.

Search now, for what I may be,
Google and I are good pals.
No paper, I saved the tree.
Give me now your rationale.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I believe it's

> Wikipedia.

**Reasons:**

Chances are you've heard of me,
Some call me an oracle.

> Wikipedia's very well-known as a source of information.

College, University,
I'm the savior late at night.

> Wikipedia's often used as a source for research, especially by students who don't have the time to look up a proper reference.

Beware, not all that you see,
Is truth or fully right.

> Wikipedia can be edited by anyone, so its information isn't always true

Search now, for what I may be,
Google and I are good pals.

> Google searches for things on Wikipedia often give the Wikipedia page as one of the first search results.

No paper, I saved the tree.

> Wikipedia's purely digital, not on paper.

Comment: +1 but I think that as OP is very experienced on this site so maybe he won't give such a baby riddle.

Comment: @manshu No, I felt like an easy one today.

Comment: @AggieKidd Huh... if you're inexperienced at 5K in eleven months, with three gold badges to boot, I'm not sure where that leaves me, or half the people on this site.  This baby riddle gets a +1 from me, purely on the principle of respect.

Comment: @raisinghellyer Well thank you. I didn't mean to say I was inexperienced, just that I gave a bit of an easier riddle on this one.